# Java weird run-time error with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, deserialization, runtime-error

I am getting this error all of the sudden. It was working before until today. I wonder if java updated or something and killed this from working.

Error I am getting:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1030230214076481435, local class serialVersionUID = -2790168081368361182
```

This happens when I do the following

```
....
ObjectInputStream open = new ObjectInputStream(openFile);
Object obj =  open.readObject(); <--- dies here
```

What should I try to fix this issue. I would love to be able to open my files again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I suspect you have switched versions of Java.  Note that the [javadoc for JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) says this:

> *"Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeans has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."*

---

> What should I try to fix this issue. I would love to be able to open my files again.

There is not much you can so apart from switching back to the JRE / JDK you were using previously.  The long-term fix is to reengineer your application to store the state some other way.

Comment: Guess I have to make my own xml serialize/deserialize function. That is going to be a PAIN! Any good tutorials on how to do something like this? Thanks.

Comment: @ScottDeutsch - you would be better off finding out why it doesn't work and trying to fix it than starting again with a totally custom XML serializer.

Answer (score 3):

It would be because you created the file `openFile` in a jdk/jre version different from the one you are running now. So the `JComponent` class' serialVersionid is different.
 Try running your application with the previous jre (cannot say if it old or new).

Answer (score 0):

Change your clsas serialVersionUID `-2790168081368361182` to `-1030230214076481435`, and have a try.

Comment: I searched for serialVersionUID = -2790168081368361182 and nothing came up. As you can see, it is not my class. it is a JComponent. So, what is the next thing I should try. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottDeutsch Sorry for my carelessness, where do you get `openFile`?